# Interpretation of the Conformal Boundary Condition

Tags: conservation-laws, conformal-field-theory, boundary-conditions, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

In 2D BCFT with a boundary on the real axis, a boundary condition is often chosen on it as
$$T(z)=\bar{T}(\bar{z}) \text{   at } z = \bar{z}. $$
This boundary condition can be interpreted as no energy flowing through the boundary if we write $T$ in the usual $x,t$ basis. This means that the energy of the system should remain conserved. But what about the flow of momentum? Should we also demand that momentum flow is zero across the boundary? Or is the boundary analogous to a hard wall that can impart any momentum (I am imagining a wave on a semi-infinite string tied to a hard wall; The wall reflects back any incoming wave-pulse elastically with an inverted momentum but with the same energy thereby conserving the energy of the system but not momentum)? In some papers, I have seen the interpretation of this boundary condition as "no energy flux" and in others as "no momentum flux". I am confused whether we are setting the energy flux to zero, the momentum flux to zero, or both to zero at the boundary.